# How can I disable "Recently Opened Files" completely in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want VS Code to keep and display a list of recently opened files. Is there a way to disable this feature completely?

Comment: Do you mean in the `File/Open Recent` main menu or elsewhere?   `search.quickOpen.includeHistory` set that to false so recent files don't appear in the Quick Open panel.

Comment: I don't want to see a list of recently opened files at all (nowhere) in VS Code. I am using Windows, I opened  **%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json** and added  **"search.quickOpen.includeHistory": false** to the file, but after closing and re-opening VS Code, I still see a list of recently opened files in the Welcome screen.

Comment: You can change the Welcome screen with `workbench.startupEditor` set it to `none` or the new untitled file - but I doubt you can get rid of just the `Recent Files` part of the welcome screen without getting rid of it all.  Are you okay with that?

Comment: Yes @Mark, not a problem with that. Thank you.

Comment: Did that accomplish what you wanted?  The`workbench.startupEditor` setting?

Comment: Sorry, no, it didn't help in my case. I am looking for a different editor right now. Thanks.

Comment: Related for Quick Open: [How to remove the "recently opened" list from the quick open panel in VS Code?](/65381759/11107541))

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, as far as I know, no, you cannot completely prevent VS Code from remembering things that you have recently opened or used.

For Quick Open, see [How to remove the "recently opened" list from the quick open panel in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65381759/11107541). I've written an answer there:

> [VS Code 1.28 added](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_exclude-recently-opened-files-from-quick-open) the `search.quickOpen.includeHistory` setting, which you can set to `false` to get roughly what you want. The relevant issue ticket is [Allow disable of recent history in "go to file" command #30770](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30770). Note Benjamin Pasero's comment at the end of that issue ticket, which says:
>
> > The list of recently opened is still shown when initially opening quick open or having no search at all.
>
> This is confirmed by their thumbs up [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157451#issuecomment-1207491367) and their comment [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87458#issuecomment-569212388) to be by-design.

You can use the `File: Clear Recently Opened` command to clear the memory of recently opened files (note that it clears recently opened files *and* workspaces (it will give a confirmation dialog)). If you want to add a keyboard shortcut, the command ID you want is `workbench.action.clearRecentFiles`. You can also manually click the "x" button for individual entries (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15340. A feature-request for a keyboard shortcut was also raised ([#31221](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/31221)) but didn't get enough community support in time to get added to the backlog)

Note that related settings typically have IDs ending in "`.history`", like `task.quickOpen.history` and `workbench.commandPalette.history`.

A feature-request was raised at [Add option to disable the recording of recently opened files and workspaces completely #182475](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182475), but it did not receive enough community support in time to get added to the backlog. You could try to re-raise it.

In VS Code 1.88, you can at least skip between sections in Quick Open by using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up/down</kbd> on Windows and Linux, and on macOS, use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>up/down</kbd>. See [related release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_88#_quick-pick-separator-navigation-keybindings). So if you want to skip past all recent files, that's an option.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.